# Prove convexity of split function (linear and quadratic)

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Prove that
> $$
>      f(x)=\begin{cases}
>        \frac{2}{3}x^2+\frac{2}{3}x-\frac{1}{12} &\quad x<-0.5 \\
>        -0.25 &\quad x\geq -0.5  \\
>      \end{cases}
> $$
> is **convex** over $\mathbb{R}$.

As far as I understand I cannot use second derivative because the function is non-differentiable (at $x=-0.5$).

If both $x,y \geq0.25$ or $x,y < 0.25$ this is easy (both cases are convex). But I couldn't find an algebric approach to prove the case where $x<-0.5$ and $y \geq -0.5$.

[image: f(x) graph]

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: The function *is* differentiable, and its derivative is non-decreasing, which should be enough for convexity.

Comment: @dxiv You are absolutely right, didn't notice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @dxiv.

I didn't notice that the function $f(x)$ actually is *differentiable*.
$$
     f'(x)=\begin{cases}
       \frac{4}{3}x+\frac{2}{3} &\quad x<-0.5 \\
       0 &\quad x\geq -0.5  \\
     \end{cases}
\quad
     f''(x)=\begin{cases}
       4/3 &\quad x<-0.5 \\
       0 &\quad x\geq -0.5  \\
     \end{cases}
$$

One can see that $f'_+(-0.5)=0=f'_-(-0.5)$  (left and right derivatives are equal), so $f$ is continuously differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#:%7E:text=A%20twice%20differentiable%20function%20of%20one%20variable%20is%20convex%20on%20an%20interval%20if%20and%20only%20if%20its%20second%20derivative%20is%20non-negative%20there):

> - differentiable function of one variable is convex on an interval if and only if its derivative is monotonically non-decreasing on that interval
> - A twice differentiable function of one variable is convex on an interval if and only if its second derivative is non-negative there